# Flex-Flow Column Wrap - Icon with Header

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to recreate a design using Advanced Custom Fields and Hard Code. I am using flex-box as CSS and would like to have the icon above text with a row of 6 columns.

Currently, my code is putting the icon on the left and the text beside it rather than reading it as a column and then a row.

Thank you for your help :)...

```
<div class="wrapper">
<section id="process">
<?php if ( have_rows( 'procces' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'procces' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_sub_field( 'process_header' ); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_sub_field( 'process_description' ); ?><p>
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'icon' ) ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'icon' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
            <div id="process-icon" class="icon-item">
                <?php $icon_image = get_sub_field( 'icon_image' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $icon_image ) : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $icon_image['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $icon_image['alt'] ); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h2><?php the_sub_field( 'icon_description' ); ?></h2>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // no rows found ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
</div>
```

```
.icon-item {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column row;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please provide an example of your current output and the output you want. Its hard to read it out of multiple while loops. Thanks

Comment: This link is in image of what I want to get https://bybec.ca/gfx/Screen%20Shot%202021-07-26%20at%207.26.50%20AM.png


This link is an image of what I am getting based on the code above https://bybec.ca/gfx/Screen%20Shot%202021-07-26%20at%207.25.24%20AM.png

Answer (score 1):

Flex will work on the direct children of the item with the property so you just want to wrap all your `.icon-item` into a `.icon-wrapper` and apply the flex to that:

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'icon' ) ) : ?>
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
  <?php while ( have_rows( 'icon' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="icon-item">
    <?php $icon_image = get_sub_field( 'icon_image' ); ?>
      <?php if ( $icon_image ) : ?>
         <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $icon_image['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $icon_image['alt'] ); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h2><?php the_sub_field( 'icon_description' ); ?></h2>
    </div><!-- close .icon-item-->
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div><!--- close .icon-wrapper-->
<?php else : ?>
  <?php // no rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd remove that `id="process-icon"` on any multiple items too.. use classes for multiple & id for singular elements (I usually just use IDs for javascript reference)

Then your css would be:

```
.icon-wrapper { 
  display: flex;
}

.icon-item { 

}
```